# Reversing a row order in a DataFrame in r from the first to the last

Tags: r

im trying to change the row order of a DataFrame , so the last digit is in the first place, the penultimate in the second place and so on.

it looks like this

```
x1=1:2
x2=1:5
x3=c(0,1,2,0)
n=max(length(x1), length(x2), length(x3))
length(x1)=n                      
length(x2)=n
length(x3)=n
a=rbind(x1,x2,x3)
a

#What im trying to do is that every row is like:

b=rev(a) #Keeping the NA where they are
```

Thanks!

Comment: `?rev` will do this for vectors ("row" does not make sense for a vector). For matrices or data.frames (objects with rows), you could use `df[rev(seq_len(nrow(df))),]` for an object named df.

Comment: its thought for a dataframe, thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `rev` function:

`rev(x1)`

Answer (score 0):

You want to use `rev`.

```
> reverse <- rev(x1)
[1] 0 1 0 0 1 2 0 0 1
```

From its [documentation](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/rev.html):

> rev provides a reversed version of its argument

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn´t work in a dataframe. (i change a bit the problem)

Answer (score 0):

As @Imo wrote:

```
x2 <-rev(x1)
```